# ajax request in jquery, data sent to the server not working

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
var p = JSON.stringify(parameter);
    console.log(p);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://abc.com/ajax.php',
        data: p,
        success: function(status) {
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
```

console.log(p) shows `{"o_fname":"hh","o_lname":"jkhk","o_email":"uifh@bjvh.com","o_phone":"","b_name":"bmnbmbm,b","b_address":"","b_city":"","b_postal":"","b_phone":""}` 
but in my `http://abc.com/ajax.php` page `print_r($_POST)` is giving me an empty array `Array()`

Comment: And what does the access log of the server say?

Comment: No error. No post variables sent to the server. but instead of passing p in data if I write {"o_fname":"hh","o_lname":"jkhk","o_email":"uifh@bjvh.com","o_phone":"","b_name":"bmnbmbm,b","b_address":"","b_city":"","b_postal":"","b_phone":""} it works then

Comment: have you tried  `contentType: 'json',` or `json_decode();`

Comment: @MohammadAdil i did. Not working

Comment: In your $.ajax() request you've set dataType: 'json', which means that the response will already be a JSON object. print_r does not return a json object. Give this some thought

Comment: @JibranKhan yes i know. While doing that I changed dataType: 'html'.
anyways any solution to my problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var p = JSON.stringify(parameter);
```

*That* is your problem.

When you pass string data to .ajax, it sends it “as-is” – but PHP only popuplates $_POST if it receives data encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

So **don’t** make your data into a string, but pass your `parameter` object directly as value for `data` – then jQuery will take care of sending it the right way, so that PHP understands what it is supposed to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think park of the problem may be that in data: you're passing the parameter details, but to the function on the other side of the jQuery you're passing a parameter name and nothing else.

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://abc.com/ajax.php',
    data: {parametername:p},
    success: function(status) {
        console.log(status);
    }
});
```

With parametername replaced with the parameter name ajax.php is expecting.

Comment: well my data is {"o_fname":"hh","o_lname":"jkhk","o_email":"uifh@bjvh.com","o_phone":"","b_name":"bmnbmbm,b","b_address":"","b_city":"","b_postal":"","b_phone":""} & this is what exactly p is. and ajax.php is expecting o_fname,o_lname &...

Comment: try changing ajax.php to expect the object you are sending and extrapolate the data you're getting from said object.    Either way, right now it's only getting an empty parameter p.